# Can the GetEncoding method load a tbl file?

Tags: c#, winforms

i am trying to use a custom encoding to read and write text in binary files, and so far, i haven't found a way to use a .tbl file in c#, i've been thinking if there is any possibility to use `Encoding.GetEncoding()` method to load the custom encoding table, if yes, may i see any example ? this is what i am trying to do exactly:

```
Encoding CustomEn = Encoding.GetEncoding("CE.tbl");
```

if not is there any method using a foreach loop to get every character and hex value in a `Dictionary`:

```
Dictionary<int, char> CustEncod = new Dictionary<int, char>();
        CustEncod.Add(hexvalue, character);
```